# discord bot moving someone to afk channel

Tags: discord.js

Ok, so I would like my discord bot to move people to afk once they deafen. the problem is that I'm not sure how to make the bot move them to the afk channel. it detects when I deafen but has an error when it tries to execute the command. any help would be much appreciated <3

Error:

```
TypeError: newState.member.setVoiceChannel is not a function
```

code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });



client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) =>
{

    if (newState.selfDeaf)
    {
        console.log('User has deafened');
        newState.member.setVoiceChannel("afkChannelId");
    }
});



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Discord bot is now online!')
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `newState.member` is of type [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and there's no `setVoiceChannel()` function.

Instead, you have to access the [`voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) property (`newState.member.voice`) and here you can use the [`setChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel) function.

---

##### TLDR

Instead of

```js
newState.member.setVoiceChannel("afkChannelId");
```

Use this:

```js
newState.member.voice.setChannel("channel ID", <reason>);
                                                  ^
                                               optional
```